# Is there a bitcoin API that includes transaction priority or input age?

Tags: bitcoin

I'm trying to add some additional security to my bitcoin payment processing. I want to allow instant delivery of digital goods without waiting for confirmations, but only if the transaction is safe, i.e. not a double spend and has a high enough fee or priority. If something abnormal is detected I want to wait for a confirmation before delivery.

I'm able to pull the needed information for checking if a tx is a double spend or has a high enough fee for its size using the blockchain.info API and blockr.io as a backup. I would also like to allow high priority transactions with no fee to be accepted as though they had a fee, just as the bitcoin network does. The problem is that I can't find an API that provides the needed info, either the tx priority or the coin age of tx inputs, which are used in priority calculations as described here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Technical_info

I could use additional API calls to reference the inputs of a tx and find the number of confirmations, but obviously a single API call would be ideal. If no such APIs exist, I have access to a full bitcoin node which I assume could somehow be used to set up my own API. In that case I'd need to be pointed toward some documentation on how to get started.

Comment: You can just use the bitcoin node. List of API calls you can make: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using my bitcoin node, [easybitcoin-php](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP), and the following PHP code.
Visiting the page and passing a tx hash will output "high priority" if the tx has a standard or higher fee, or if it has no fee but high enough priority, otherwise it will output "low priority," or "error" if there was a problem.

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/easybitcoin.php');

$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('user', 'pass', '127.0.0.1', '8332');

$tx_hash = $_GET['tx'];
$tx = $bitcoin->getrawtransaction($tx_hash, 1);

$coin_age = 0;
$in_value = 0;
$out_value = 0;
$output_too_small = false;

foreach($tx['vin'] as $input) {
  $tx_in = $bitcoin->getrawtransaction($input['txid'], 1);
  $value = $tx_in['vout'][$input['vout']]['value'];
  $coin_age += $value * 1e8 * $tx_in['confirmations'];
  $in_value += $value;
}
foreach($tx['vout'] as $output) {
  $out_value += $output['value'];
  if ($output['value'] < 0.01) {
    $output_too_small = true;
  }
}

$size = strlen($tx['hex']) / 2;
$priority = $coin_age / $size;
$fee_per_byte = (($in_value - $out_value) * 1e8) / $size;

if (is_numeric($priority)) {
  if (($priority > 57600000 && $size < 1000 && $output_too_small == false) || $fee_per_byte >= 10) {
    echo 'high priority';
  } else {
    echo 'low priority';
  }
} else {
  echo 'error';
}
?>
```